# Deriving Wavelength from Relative Intensity with Broad Spectrum Light Sensor

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, wavelength, optical-materials, experimental-technology

I have [this broad spectrum light sensor](https://www.pasco.com/products/sensors/pasport/ps-2150#desc-panel) and it gives me readings in relative intensity, but says that it's able to measure the wavelength. The documentation is rather unhelpful, so I was wondering how you properly calibrate the broad spectrum light sensor and then how you read the data in order to find the wavelength?
Thanks, have a good day.

Comment: From the link and information therein, it appears that you would have to calibrate the system using a line source spectral lamp, e.g., neon or mercury, and their known line wavelengths would then correspond to angular sensor positions. I assume a transmission diffraction grating is used as the dispersive element.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
If I lack the rest of the kit, is there still a way to determine the wavelength?

Comment: I don’t see how: the detector is a thermopile, so it basically detects heat. Any light going into the detector gets absorbed and the resulting temperature increase is proportional to the absorbed light energy. You might try contacting the Pasco folks to see if they can elaborate a bit. Also, I upvoted and thank you for the link: I need a mercury spectral lamp and power supply to calibrate my own project (a homemade echelle spectrograph) and Pasco has what I need. Right now, I am making do with a white light compact fluorescent lamp and its mercury emission lines.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Glad the link proved helpful. Have a great day!